# Using Regex to remove brackets and contents if the contents contain any non digits

Tags: python, regex, brackets

I want to remove the [] and contents if there is at least one non digit within the [].

Input: `Tag1[aA], Tag2[55].AA[*], Tag3[A1];`

Output: `Tag1, Tag2[55].AA, Tag3;`

I have tried the below, however it only works on exact matches within the brackets.

```
import re

line = "'Tag1[aA], Tag2[55].AA[*], Tag3[A1];"

# removes the [] if contents contain non digits only
pattern = r'\[\D+\]'
s = re.sub(pattern, '', line)
print(s)

> "'Tag1, Tag2[55].AA, Tag3[A1];"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
\[[^][]*[^][\d][^][]*]
```

The pattern matches:

- `\[` Match `[`
- `[^][\d]*` Optionally match any char except `[` and `]`
- `[^][\d]` Match a single char other than `[` `]` or a digit
- `[^][\d]*` Optionally match any char except `[` and `]`
- `]` Match `]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/leRHnU/1)

```
import re

print(re.sub(r"\[[^][]*[^][\d][^][]*]", "", "Tag1[aA], Tag2[55].AA[*], Tag3[A1];"))
```

Output

```
Tag1, Tag2[55].AA, Tag3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, I have considered some additional cases also.

```
import re

line = "'Tag1[aA], Tag2[55].AA[*], Tag3[A1],Tag4[34],Tag5[1B];"

# removes the [] if contents contain non digits only
pattern = r'(\[\D.+?\]?|\[.\D.+?\]?)'
s = re.sub(pattern, '', line)
print(s)
```

Output:
`'Tag1, Tag2[55].AA, Tag3,Tag4[34],Tag5;`